# How can implement powerpoint presentation in ipad through objective c codes

Tags: ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one open a power point document in an iPad application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172017/how-can-one-open-a-power-point-document-in-an-ipad-application)

I have to present a power point presentation from  a web in an ipad application.Is there any free libraries in ios to convert .ppt format in to any other format ??How can I implement animations for that presentation .Please give some idea for implementing the above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but Apple's documentation says that a UIWebView is able to display .ppt documents.  Search for their tech. note QA1630 for a complete list of supported types.